# switching from fixtures to Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

Rails 3.0.3....

I'm just starting out with Factory Girl, having had little success with the standard fixtures approach.  I've commented out `fixtures :all` from the test/test_helper.rb file and have created a factories file.

My problem is that the sequence feature doesn't seem to work:

```
# test/factories.rb
Factory.sequence :clearer_name do |n|
   "Clearer_#{n}"
end

Factory.define :clearer do |f|
   f.name Factory.next(:clearer_name)
end
```

My (functional) test is only slightly different from standard:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClearersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   setup do
      @clearer = Factory.create(:clearer)
   end

test "should get index" do
   get :index
   assert_response :success
   assert_not_nil assigns(:clearers)
 end

 test "should get new" do
   get :new
   assert_response :success
 end

 test "should create clearer" do
   assert_difference('Clearer.count') do
     post :create, :clearer => @clearer.attributes
   end

   assert_redirected_to clearer_path(assigns(:clearer))
 end
```

When I run `rake test` I get:

```
test_should_create_clearer(ClearersControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: column name is not unique: INSERT INTO "clearers" ("active", "updated_at", "name", "created_at") VALUES ('t', '2011-02-20 08:53:37.040200', 'Clearer_1', '2011-02-20 08:53:37.040200')
```

...as if it's not continuing the sequence.

Any tips?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**: heres my test file:

```
#clearers_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class ClearersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @clearer = Factory.create(:clearer)
  end

  test "should create clearer" do

    assert_difference('Clearer.count') do
      # does not work without this:
      Clearer.destroy_all 
      post :create, :clearer => @clearer.attributes
    end
end
```

I can get this to work by putting `Clearer.destroy_all` at the top of the test method as shown, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but Rails 3.0.4 is out and includes important security fixes so I'd recommend updating.

Comment: I think I see the problem now that you've added the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see - In your setup, you're creating a Clearer instance.  The Factory.create method builds and saves a new record and returns it.

The problem is that you're then attempting to create another instance in your "should create clearer" test but you're re-using the existing instance's attributes.

If you want Factory to return fresh attributes (and the next name sequence), you need to ask it for new attributes:

```
test "should create clearer" do
  assert_difference('Clearer.count') do
    post :create, :clearer => Factory.attributes_for(:clearer)
  end
end
```

You should only be using that existing @clearer instance in the context of an existing record, not where you want a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't starting with a fresh database is my guess.  There's lots of reasons this could be happen, but you can verify that's the problem by adding a Clearer.destroy_all in your setup function, before creating one.

Answer (score 0):

Sequences and other attribute values that are calculated at runtime need to be procs, not static values.

Change:

```
Factory.define :clearer do |f|
   f.name Factory.next(:clearer_name)
end
```

to:

```
Factory.define :clearer do |f|
   f.name {Factory.next(:clearer_name)}
end
```